# Create single framework dependent exe file with .NET Core 3.1 and only include third party dll

Tags: .net-core

is it possible to create a single exe file with only third party libraries included?

I have a small console app with a third party library. 
If i use the following code it is still 26 MB.

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true
```

Comment: So you don't like PublishSingleFile.  Having to deploy the entire .NETCore runtime as well as your own code is indeed not much to like, you'd favor using dotnet.exe to run your program.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a solution.

Run the following code in the folder which contains the project file.

```
dotnet publish -r <rid> --self-contained=false /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

You can get the rid (runtime id) from:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog